# what does compute() do in dask?

Tags: python, dask

I am new to dask and don't understand what does compute() method exactly do in dask? does it a method to print the object where it call on? I have read the documentation from its website and not sure if I understand the terms "concrete values" and "lazy dask".

> You can turn any dask collection into a concrete value by calling the .compute() method or dask.compute(...) function. This function will block until the computation is finished, going straight from a lazy dask collection to a concrete value in local memory.

what I mean by saying "does it a method to print the object where it call on?" is that, when I create a dask object and call it in spyder console it resulted in `dask.array<arange, shape=(11,), dtype=int32, chunksize=(5,)>` and when I call the compute() method on it, it prints the object. [image: dask]

the x object has been created via below code:

```
x = da.arange(11, chunks=5)
```

Comment: When you create an object, it's just a blueprint until you call `.compute()`. That is when the job gets distributed to all the workers and actual function gets called or concrete values are generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good and simple introduction into this topic can be found at
https://towardsdatascience.com/why-every-data-scientist-should-use-dask-81b2b850e15b
(find chapter *Parallel Processing with Dask*).

The first step is to prepare a *computation graph*:

```
computation_graph = sum_list([square(i) for i in items])
```

The above instruction only created a "recipe" how to perform
the computation, but no actual computation has been started (yet).

A little below there is the next instruction:

```
print("Result", computation_graph.compute())
```

which **starts the computation**, and because it is within a *print*
instruction, we have also a demonstration of how the computation runs.

So using *Dask* involves usually 4 steps:

- Acquire (read) source data.
- Prepare a recipe what should be computed.
- Start the computation (and just this performs *compute*).
- "Consume" the result of computation (after it is completed).