# Unable to use Dask dataframe with Plotly Dash

Tags: python, dask, plotly-dash

I am trying to use Dask to read a CSV file and plot it using Plotly Dash. While doing that I am getting following error:

```
dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for property `figure` of component `graph`
returned a value which is not JSON serializable.

In general, Dash properties can only be dash components, strings,
dictionaries, numbers, None, or lists of those.
```

Below is my code for reference:

```
@dashapp.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')])
    def update_graph(dropdown_value):
        data = dd.read_csv('data/output.csv')
        
        return {
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Graph of {}'.format(dropdown_value),
                'margin': {
                    'l': 20,
                    'b': 20,
                    'r': 10,
                    't': 60
                }
            },
            'data': [{'x': data['col1'].values, 'y': data['col2'].values}]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `compute()` on `data` before you pass it to the graph dictionary.

When you do this:

```
data = dd.read_csv('data/output.csv')
```

the type of `data` is `<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>`.

Dash doesn't know what a Dask Dataframe is. So you need to call `compute` so you get a Pandas dataframe that you can get the column values from as a list:

```
@dashapp.callback(Output("graph", "figure"), [Input("dropdown", "children")])
def update_graph(dropdown_value):
    data = dd.read_csv("data/output.csv").compute()

    return {
        "layout": {
            "title": "Graph of {}".format(dropdown_value),
            "margin": {"l": 20, "b": 20, "r": 10, "t": 60},
        },
        "data": [{"x": data["col1"].values, "y": data["col2"].values}],
    }
```

Comment: Then I won't be able to utilize the speed benefit of Dask. I could have directly use Pandas.

Comment: [Dask's `read_csv` method parallelizes Pandas' `read_csv` method](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#storage-and-conversion). So there *is* a difference from directly using Pandas. Whatever you want to do, at some point the data is going to have to be resolved to something Dash understands. You could of course do some operations like aggregations before calling `compute`, but at some point you're going to have to call `compute`. As the error says Dash is not going to accept something that is not JSON serializable.

Comment: Whether it's actually worth it in your case to use Dask Dataframe here instead of using a Pandas Dataframe directly for speed benefits I can't really say. That depends on the size of the data among other factors. I think the answer to that question can be better found by making a benchmark.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58719683/9098350) for more info on what `compute` does.

Comment: I found another way to use parallel processing. I used modin which allows pandas dataframe as it is without it splitting into parts.